# How can I pass a uint value from vertex shader to geometry shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I want to calculate a hash value for each triangle in my geometry shader. I want this hash to be random among triangles but determinate across time.

There seems not to be a "triangle id" for me. So I use their first vertices' id. Maybe not perfect.

But vertex id is only valid in vertex shader. If I want to pass this id to geometry shader, how to define the `v2g` struct?

I define `v2g` this way but don't know what semantics it should have. I can't find any example that have an `uint` value in `v2g` struct.

```
struct v2g {
    float4  position: SV_POSITION;
    float3  normal: NORMAL;
    float4  color: COLOR;
    uint    id;
};
```

Do I have to make id field a `float` or even `double`?